# How to overlay a line on a visio 2010 diagram

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

I have a drawing of a process that has three swim lanes.  Imagine taking a print out of that and using a yellow highlighter, drawing a line of the actual process a customer experienced.  How can I draw that line in visio to overlay on the process map?

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do. Use the **line tool**, select the line width and colour as you want and set the transparancy to 50%. You could also use the standard connector instead of the line tool.

I've written an article about this at [Path through flowchart](http://www.paulherber.co.uk/articles/visio-articles/path-through-flowchart/)

[image: overlayed lines]